# Error when trying to use a helper function to count the number of syllables in a text file [Python]

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to programming and is currently trying to learn Python. My objective is to use web scraping, or more specifically BeautifulSoup to grab the syllables of a word on dictionary.com and count how many syllables there are. Through that, I want to use that function to count how many syllables there are in a large text file. However, I seem to be stuck on trying to figure out where my code went wrong when I try to implement the helper function "count_syllables" in the function "syllables". Below is a part of my code and the error message:

```
def count_syllables(keyword):
    url = 'http://dictionary.com/browse/{}'.format(keyword)
    web_object = requests.get(url)
    text = web_object.text
    text = text.encode('utf-8')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
    div = [div for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class': "waypoint-wrapper header-row header-first-row"})]
    span = [div.find(name='span') for div in div]
    span = span[0]['data-syllable']
    strip_mid = span.replace('·', ' ')
    syl = len(strip_mid.split())

    return syl

grab_text = ['airplane.txt', 'sea.txt']
for file in grab_text:
    with open(os.path.join("bigfile", file), "r") as infile:
        all_text = infile.readlines()
        entry = ''.join(all_text)

        def syllables():
            split_words = entry.split()
            print('HERE ARE THE NUMBER OF SYLLABLES IN', file.upper())
            for words in split_words:
                words = count_syllables(split_words)
                add_words = sum(words)
                return add_words

        print(syllables())
```

## Error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Can you also mention the line number of error?

Comment: It appears that the error is in line 9 and 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like sometimes

```
span = span[0]['data-syllable']
```

span will be an empty list, so you cannot index into it.

You need to implement some kind of check. You could do try-catch, if statements, or something else.

Comment: So would I just return nothing if span is an empty list in my def count_syllables function?

Comment: If nothing makes sense for what you you're trying to do, yeah. A quick glance it looks like you're returning ints? So you can `return 0` if span is empty.

Comment: Yes you can do that.